# Training model in R via neuralnet with list of labelled data

Tags: r, neural-network

I want to train a model for a multiclass classification in R studio, using neuralnet.

It is a list of stock market data in short, 50 sample dataframes of each class (there are 3 classes, Long, Short, and Neutral). The format of the dataframe is as follows:
M1DateTime (POSIXct format), M1Open, M1High, M1Low, M1Close (all doubles), etc, a total of 10 variables, 200 observations each, then a LABEL is assigned to each of these to a total of 300 entries in the list. So something like this:

```
[[1]]
sample1(10var*200obs' -including POSIX time)
LABEL = LONG
[[3]]
sample2(10var*200obs' -including POSIX time)
LABEL = LONG
[[5]]
sample3(10var*200obs' -including POSIX time)
LABEL = SHORT
[[7]]
sample4(10var*200obs' -including POSIX time)
LABEL = NEUTRAL
...
[[299]]
sample150(10var*200obs' -including POSIX time)
LABEL = SHORT
```

My question is: How can I properly train that kind of data to the model? Every page I found, and even the documentation was telling dataframes in their examples.

The command I tried did not work

```
trained.model <- neuralnet(LABEL ~ M1O + M1H + M1L + M1C + M1SMA10 + M1SMA21 + M1RSI + M1RSISMA10 + M1RSISMA40, data = train.samples, hidden = c(11,11), linear.output = F)
```

I got the error message:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Then I tried

```
trained.model <- neuralnet(LABEL ~ train.samples[1], data = train.samples, hidden = c(11,11), linear.output = F)
```

error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I think, it's a kind of a syntax issue, but I couldn't find a guide on the topic yet. Is it even possible to train a model with a list (I guess so), if yes, then please advise, if not, then what other method should I use instead for this problem?

Comment: some of your variables have only 1 factor, thats why it cannot regress

Comment: Guess it is the LABEL then, which is a CHR string and added manually as a list item, right after each and every sample dataframe, which of those look like [this](https://pastebin.com/Mt14kM9h), so basically the dataframes themselves are not having any single factor data. I did not want to add the label into the dataframes, and I wanted to separate the samples, thats why I'm using the list.